# TEdit with clear button

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I have a TEdit control where the "StyleLookup" property is set to "clearingeditstyle". The control is rendered perfect on Win64 an Android with an X on the right edge. But I could not find an "OnClear" event on the TEdit. What event is called, when th user klicks or presses the clear X?

I have some 2yrs worked in Delphi / VCL. Now I'm writing my first Firemonkey commercial app. Very difficult.

Comment: Setting *"StyleLookup" property is set to "clearingeditstyle"*, will show you an "X" on the button, but will not provide the action you expect. Instead, to  get it working, right click on the `TEdit` and select `AddItem - TClearEditButton` from the popup menu.  (This is not mentioned in the answer to which you have been referred.)